# How to build hash map of sets

Tags: clojure

I think I am struggling with some basics of clojure's immutable hash map.

I want to turn a list of tuples in to a hash-map

```
([:a 2] [:b 3] [:a 1] [:b 3]) ==> {:a #{2 1}, :b #{3}}
```

That is, in python I would do:

```
hash_map = defaultdict(set)

for key, value in my_list:
  hash_map[key].add(value)
```

How should I do this in clojure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, so many useful Clojure functions to touch:

```
(reduce
  (fn [m [k v]]
    (update-in m [k] (fnil conj #{}) v))
  {} data)
;; => {:b #{3}, :a #{1 2}}
```

It's actually quite close to the Python code: you iterate over the seq using `reduce`, add the value to the map using `update-in` and `conj` and make sure the value is initialized with an empty set using `fnil`.

Comment: You could also make use of the optional get parameter to set a default when key lookup returns nil.  (reduce (fn [m [k v]] (assoc m k (conj (get m k #{}) v ))) {} data)

Comment: Sure, there are multiple approaches. But `update-in`+`fnil` is probably the idiomatic shorthand for `get`+`assoc`+default value.

Comment: Since get+assoc is literally what update-in does, I doubt one can say update-in+fnil is more idiomatic in an unnested map. But the difference is trivial.

Comment: idiomatic _shorthand_; both are idiomatic of course but if I had to choose a way to express what I'm doing more concisely, this would probably be it. :)

Comment: Nielsk the `update-in` + `fnil` version has less noise. Idioms aren't just about what the code does, but also how it gets expressed.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn pairs-to-hash [pairs]
  (into {}
        (map (fn [kv]
               [(key kv) (->> kv val (map second) set)])
             (group-by first pairs))))

(pairs-to-hash '([:a 2] [:b 3] [:a 1] [:b 3]))
```

This was a quick attempt that I think could be neatened up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Slow but sure:

```
(defn pairs-to-graph [pairs]
  (apply merge-with clojure.set/union 
        (map (fn [[k v]] {k #{v}}) pairs)))

(pairs-to-graph '([:a 2] [:b 3] [:a 1] [:b 3]))
;{:b #{3}, :a #{1 2}}
```